# Minimum and maximum on the closed disk $\,D(0,1)-f(z)=z^2-z$

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

Let $\,f\left(z\right)=z^2-z.\,$ Find the maximum and the minimum of $\,\left\lvert\, f\left(z\right)\,\right\rvert\,$ on the closed disk $\,\overline{D(0,1)}$.
Compute $\,f'$ to the point where the minimum and maximum are achieved.

I just really don't know how I can do this question. Is anyone could give me a hint or a result to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $f$ is holomorphic so $|f(z)|$ has a maximum on the boundary by maximum modulus

By parallelogram law for $0,\ -z,\ z^2,\ z^2-z$ where $|z|=1$, $$ |f(z)|^2+|z^2+z|^2=4 $$

(1) That is $$ |z-1|^2+|z+1|^2=4 $$ If $z=-1$, then we have a maximum $|f(-1)|=2$ So $f'(-1)=-3$

(2) Also if $z=1$, then we have a minimum $|f(1)|=0$ on the boundary Hence $f'(1)=1$

(3) Clearly $|f(z)|$ has a minimum $0$ on the boundary. So $f(z)=0$ implies that $z=0$ So $f'(0)=-1$

Answer (score 2):

If $|z|=1 $ then $z=e^{it} $ hence $z^2 - z= e^{2it} - e^{it} =\cos 2t - \cos t + i (\sin 2t - \sin t)$ thus $$|z^2 -z | =\sqrt{ (\cos 2t - \cos t)^2 +  (\sin 2t - \sin t)^2 }=\sqrt{2 -2(\sin 2t \sin t +\cos 2t \cos t )} =\sqrt{2 - 2\cos (2t-t)}=\sqrt{2-2\cos t} \leq \sqrt{4} =2$$

and the equality is attained if $t=\pi.$
On the other hand $|z^2 -z |=0$ if $z=1\vee z=0.$
Since $f(z) =z^2 -z $ is holomorphic the maximum is equal to $2$ and minimum is equal to $0.$